# What kind of Linux can verify all of its files / packages like debsums(Debian), but more?

Tags: security, package-management

```
# debsums -a, --all  check configuration files (normally excluded)
```

However, there is large amount of temporary, ancillary files here and there, not only in tmp-dir.

About 4,000 of binaries .pyc files of python, which can not be disabled by default:

```
# cat /etc/python/debian_config  
# standard, optimize 
byte-compile = standard
```

etc...

Is there any distribution of Linux, which have on-line repositories with capability to verify each file installed on my machine securely ?

I'm talking about **packages manager** like Host-based Intrusion Detection System with modern cryptography capable to prevent/detect any infection.

Answer (score 6):

RPM-based systems have `rpm -q --verify`, which does similar things.

However, I don't think either of these features is a suitable alternative to an IDS. The key problem is that the checksums are on the machine in question, so if it has been compromised, you can't trust the local checksums.

Maybe you can get fresh checksums from the Internet repositories, but I still think you're going about it the wrong way to use package checksums for this.

A far better option is to use a dedicated file integrity checker like [AIDE](http://aide.sourceforge.net) or [Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.org). These tools let you compute the checksums on the system once you've gotten it into a known-good state, then store them on removable read-only media (e.g. CD-R) for later comparison.

Another problem with the package checksum method is that it can't be expected to check things like `/etc` files, since they're known to change from the stock contents on purpose. With something like AIDE, you compute the checksums *after* you make your changes to the stock versions of these files, so you can confidently say whether a change was expected or not.

That's not to say that package checksum verification is useless. It's just that it's not intended to detect malicious modification. It's for detecting accidental changes, so they can be fixed. For example, someone might have done a ham-handed `chmod -R` command, then hit <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> before it ran for very long once they realized their mistake, so you verify the packages to find out which packages' file permissions got munged.

Comment: If it helps you can use the shortcut links `rpmverify` and `rpmquery` to perform tasks when dealing with RPMs too. These are overloaded links to the executable rpm, but save from having to remember the different combinations of switches to `rpm`.

Comment: It seems to me AIDE doesn't protect against corruption that occurs before you run it.  I don't see any way to be certain the files are correct other than verifying them against the package signatures, and doing that on a trusted system as you say.

You say a file integrity checker lets you "compute the checksums on the system once you've gotten it into a known-good state" -- but a known-good state is what you start at, not something you can reach.  If the system was compromised it could have malware hiding in all sorts of undetectable places.  This could happen at the first package install!

Comment: @slm - How reliable are `rpmverify`, `rpmquery` and `rpm --verify` to attest to the integrity of packages?

Comment: @WarrenYoung - Does `rpm --verify` check the integrity of packages and configurations to known and verified online repositories? If no, how reliable is `rpm --verify`?

Comment: @Motivated: I thought I made it pretty clear in the answer that `rpm --verify` is no replacement for an IDS or a file checksumming system. For just one thing, configuration files only check out as "verified" when they're unchanged from the stock version, which gives either a non-functional or near-useless configuration for many packages. (e.g. Postfix, Samba, Bind...) So, verify tells you these files are changed, but *you knew that already*, if you are making active use of these services. It doesn't tell you that someone's tampered with your known-good configuration.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - I realized that `rpm --verify` may not be a like for like replacement of an IDS or file integrity solution. I was attempting to clarify if the command verified the integrity of packages and configurations to known and trusted online repositories or does it verify these to a local database? If the latter, is the database updated each time an online repository is? It isn't clear to me as to the relationship between `rpm --verify` and the the package sources. It's an additional reflection on fuzzyTew's comment.

Comment: @Motivated: Quoting the very answer: "The key problem is that the checksums are on the machine in question..." So no, it doesn't download the checksums from a trusted online source, unless you consider the original RPM download to be that source. But even if you do, the point is that if someone can compromise your system's config files and such, they can probably tamper with the RPM DB, too.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - Thanks for clarifying that. If `rpm` isn't downloading the checksums, it suggests that the checksums are not being updated with each package update for example. If yes, what are the use cases that `rpm --verify` supports? Is there any value in using `rpm --verify`?

Comment: Once again, the checksums are in the downloaded RPM, but are then *stored* in the local RPM DB. The checksums are for the actual files in the RPM. As for the value of verifying, it can detect non-malicious damage, such as disk corruption, unintentional modification, etc.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - Thanks. If i have understood you correctly, do you mean to say that the checksum is part of the header information in a RPM? If yes, how does rpm --verify verify its authenticity i.e. it's non-malicious? Based on your feedback, my understanding is that it cannot. Additionally, when you say non-malicious indicators such as unintentional modifications, how does it verify these if it does not compare it to any other canonical source?

Comment: @WarrenYoung - The reason i ask is because i'm attempting to understand the use of rpm --verify in the real world scenario. If i am using a package manager, isn't it already performing operations such as verifying modifications, corruption etc?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Warren's solution (AIDE), but if you really want to watch your system, using something like CFEngine or a derivative (Puppet, Chef, saltstack, whatever) to manage the entire contents of your filesystem.  Use a package manager to install files, a config management system to manage the contents of all config files, and alert when anything changes outside of your config system (as well as probably changing things back).  The deeper you go, the more involved the solution, though.  Completely managing a system and all files on it is a really big undertaking.  CFEngine can learn checksums of files and watch them for you as well, if you don't care about the contents as much as just getting notified when things change.  The others probably have similar functionality, but they'll be slower.  I can tell you that you really really don't want to do frequent recursive filesystem monitoring with Puppet.  Then again, the learning curves for different tools are different.  AIDE is pretty easy to pick up, CFEngine can be a minor challenge.